# Character Animation with Metal

Tags: ios, swift, metal

I have just delved into the world of Metal, and I thought that I'd got the hang of it! But then it occurred to me that if I wanted to make a game, then static objects moving around a screen wouldn't suffice. So my question is, 'Is it possible to create animations for models with Metal?'

I have looked at using other APIs, such as SpriteKit, and SceneKit, but I found that they do not support shaders, and are not as powerful as Metal.

The only way that I can think about how I would go about this, is by creating 60 different models, and then loading each one one after the other, to give a 'stop-motion' kind of effect, but I think that this would probably be incredibly inefficient, and was hoping that there was an easier answer?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: FIY: Scene Kit *does* support both skeletal animation, custom shaders, and multi-pass rendering. It *is* however true that they are not as powerful as Metal.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, there are other, more efficient ways to do animation. But before getting into that, a warning: it really looks like you're barking up the wrong tree here.

Metal is a (conceptually) very low-level interface. You use Metal to talk (almost) directly to the GPU, so to work with it you need to think (sort of) like a GPU: in terms of data buffers, vertex transformations, etc. You seem to be working at a much higher conceptual level, so you're probably better served by one of the high-level game engines: SpriteKit for 2D or SceneKit for 3D. (Or a third party engine like Cocos or Unity.) Metal, on the other hand, is better suited for building those game engines.

SpriteKit and SceneKit *do* support shaders. Look at [`SKShader`](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKShader_Ref/index.html) and [`SCNShadable`](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/SceneKit/Reference/SCNShadable_Protocol/index.html) in the docs (and be sure to click the "More" links to read the full overviews). SceneKit also supports character animations (aka skeletal animation aka skinning): typically one designs and rigs a model for animation in an external authoring tool (Maya, Blender, etc), then uses SceneKit to work with the animations at run time.

It is possible to do things like GPU-based skeletal animation in Metal. But I haven't seen any tutorials or similar written about it yet, probably because Metal is such a new technology. Fundamentally, though, it'd be based on the same sorts of techniques you'd use for skeletal animation in OpenGL or Direct3D — and much has been written about animation for those technologies. If you're willing to invest the time and energy to work at a low level, adapting the subject matter from GL/D3D tutorials is relatively easy.

Comment: Hey! Thanks for the info! Just to get things straight, if I was to use Metal, then I would have to program in the skeletal animation from scratch in order to make the character animate? Thanks again for your help!

Comment: Yes, you'd have to write your own Metal-based skeletal animation code. (Unless you're using a third-party, Metal-based, higher-level game engine such as Unreal or Unity **and** said engine has its own support for skeletal animation.)

Comment: @rickster Is it possible to animate skeletal character in `SceneKit` using Metal Shader ?

Answer (score 1):

You can do skeletal animation in Metal, SCNKit would be using the GPU to deform the mesh as well. But to do it in Metal you would need to pass skin weights, along with bone matrices for the bind pose and the transformations of the bones as they animate then calculate the new vertex positions based on these. In fact I think you need the inverse of the bind pose matrices. Each mesh vertex is then transformed by a weighted sum of transformations dictated by the skin weights.

I tried it but screwed it up somehow it didn’t deform properly, I don’t know if I’d obtained the wrong matrices from my custom script to grab animation data from blender or a bug in my shader maths or from the weights.

It was probably close, but with all the possible things that I may have got wrong in the process it was difficult to fix so I abandoned it in the end.

Probably easier to stick with SceneKit and let apple take care of the rest or use an existing game engine such as Unity.

Then again if you want a challenge, I’m sure it’s possible, just a little tricky. You could try CPU first to make sure the maths is ok then port it to the GPU to make it faster?

Answer (score 1):

SceneKit do support shaders. And an object that manages the relationship between skeletal animations and the nodes and geometries they animate is `SCNSkinner` from SceneKit.

Typically, you need to create a skinned model using, for example, **Autodesk Maya**, save it along with animations that use the skeleton, in a scene file. You load the model from the scene file and pose or animate it in your app, either by using animation objects also loaded from the scene file or by directly manipulating the nodes in the skeleton. That's it.

Watch this 7-parts video [about Blender's skeletal system and how to use it in SceneKit](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8Jb3v2HRv_E).

[image]

```
convenience init(baseGeometry: SCNGeometry?,              //character
                 bones: [SCNNode],                        //array of bones
                 boneInverseBindTransforms: [NSValue]?,   //ibt of matrix4
                 boneWeights: SCNGeometrySource,          //influence on geometry
                 boneIndices: SCNGeometrySource           //index mapping
                 )
```